# Exclude Generated Code from C# SONAR Analysis

Tags: c#, sonarqube

So in VS2013 we have an option of "**Suppress Results from generated Code(Managed only)**"

Do we have a similar option when performing analysis via `SONAR` ?

The below code reports violations when the above option is unchecked but I don't see any option in SONAR to make use of the above option.
I did try the `Sonar.dotnet.excludeGeneratedCode = true` option, but doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> YieldTest()
    {
        foreach(var num in Enumerable.Range(100, 100))
            yield return string.Format("{0}", num);
    }
```

Comment: How can the analyzer know that it should exclude that method from analysis? Did you mark it with some special attributes, is it in a specifically named file, or special project type?

Comment: Hi Dinesh, I tried marking the method with the [GeneratedCode] attribute but it didn't help.

Comment: If you analyze the above method in Visual Studio with the above option unchecked I get a violation for CA1305  and with checked I get no violation.

Comment: Ok, I managed to reproduce that behavior in VS2015. Now, what is exactly the issue you are facing? CA1305 is reporting in SonarQube, but not in Visual Studio when the "Suppress Results from generated Code" flag is set? Or is it another issue?

Comment: Hi Dinesh,  Yes that is the issues I am facing. It would be great if we can have a similar option  to suppress generated code on Sonar. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSBuild SonarQube Runner (at least in versions 1.0 and 1.0.1) always forces the "**Suppress Results from generated Code(Managed only)**" flag to be checked when FxCop is launched during the build. See [SonarQube.Integration.targets#L342](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.0.1/SonarQube.MSBuild.Tasks/Targets/SonarQube.Integration.targets#L342)

You can verify this behavior in your build logs, by looking at the command launched during the `RunCodeAnalysis:` phase:

```
RunCodeAnalysis:
  Running Code Analysis...
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe 
  /outputCulture:1033
  /out:"bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe.CodeAnalysisLog.xml" /file:"bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe" /ruleSet:"=C:\Users\dinesh\Desktop\tmp\ConsoleApplication1\.sonarqube\conf\\SonarQubeFxCop-cs.ruleset"
  [... references ...]
  /rulesetdirectory:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets"
  /rule:"-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\\Rules"
  /searchgac /ignoreinvalidtargets /forceoutput /successfile **/ignoregeneratedcode** /saveMessagesToReport:Active /timeout:120 /reportMissingIndirectAssemblies
```

You should see the **/ignoregeneratedcode** being passed to FxCopCmd.exe.

Now, only FxCop rules will be suppressed by this flag. StyleCop and ReSharper rules for example will not understand this flag and will still report on that method.

FYI, it seems that FxCop excludes this method because of the presence of the `yield` statement: The C# compiler generates quite complex IL code in the assembly for this statement. FxCop analyzes assemblies (and not the source code), which is why it has to treat the `yield` statement as generated code.

So, in SonarQube, you should not see an issue for `CA1305`, regardless of whether or not you checked the "Suppress Results from generated Code(Managed only)" on your project.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, I just checked the log and FxCop is being invoked with just "/forceoutput /searchgac " flags, I don't see /ignoregeneratedcode :(. Do I have to make any config changes to SONAR, to make this flag active ?

Comment: As you can see in the MSBuild SonarQube Runner sources, it does try to force this flag to `true`. What I can imagine is that some other customized targets is setting that to `false` again later on. Could you try to put that method in a new Console Application project (with the default .csproj file)? If that does not help, could you try to run the analysis from another machine? Can you also provide the MSBuild version you are using the build your project? We've intensively tested 12 & 14.

Comment: I am trying out the MsBuild Runner, Will update you. Thank you

Comment: I forgot mention, I was not using the MsBuild Runner but the Sonar Runner.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, I tried out the MsBuild Runner and it is now ignoring the generated code, My setup was using SONARQube runner. Can this flag be set in the SONAR runner ? If not then I will have to migrate to MsBuild Runner :(. Thank you your help.

Comment: The sonar-runner is no longer officially supported to analyze .NET projects, so you'll really want to start to migrate your projects to use the MSBuild SonarQube Runner, which is being developed by SonarSource jointly with Microsoft and makes the analysis of .NET projects much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I run with this property set and it excludes the generated code.

```
sonar.exclusions=**/*.Tests/**,**/*Language.Designer.cs,**/*.generated.cs
```

If we look into detail, the exclusion contains these parts:

- **/*.Tests/** ==> exclude all code found in a folder ending with .Tests (recursive)
- **/*Language.Designer.cs ==> exclude all resource id files
- **/*.generated.cs ==> exclude all files ending in .generated.cs

If you use other generated files (like winforms designer files) you will need to ask your own masks.

Comment: I Filip, I tried this approach but it doesnt seems to work.